# Query para MYSQL com IF para validar diversos campos da tabela

Tags: sql

Estou desenvolvendo um Classificados de Imóveis, com isso preciso filtrar alguns campos caso o internauta deseje, tais como: Número de quartos, Número de vagas para garagem, Número de banheiros, etc.

Preciso que a Query tenha IF para que possa validar SE as variáveis estiverem preenchidas possa filtrar o campo X ou Y ou os dois.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT type, property_type, city, region, neighborhood, price, rooms,
 bathrooms, parking, content, img1, urlimovel, logo, url 
FROM imoveis where type = '$oquedeseja' AND goal = '$idfinalidade' 
AND property_type = '$idtipo' AND region = '$iduf' AND city = '$idcidade'
AND rooms = '$nquartos'
```

**AND rooms = '$nquartos'**

No exemplo acima ele verificaria SE a variável **$nquartos** não estiver vazia ele filtraria por **rooms**.

Comment: Acho melhor fazer essas condições na aplicação, via PHP (no caso) ficaria mais agradável.

Comment: @lvcs eu tenho iniciado este processo no PHP mas como preciso de diversos filtros, está ficando muito complexo. Pois se validar as condições direto na query ficará mais fácil e eu usaria apenas query para validar tudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível solução é considerar um valor padrão quando a variável não está selecionada na aplicação. Por exemplo `-1`.

```
SELECT type, property_type, city, region, neighborhood, price, rooms,
 bathrooms, parking, content, img1, urlimovel, logo, url 
FROM imoveis 
where (type = '$oquedeseja' or '$oquedeseja' = -1) 
AND (goal = '$idfinalidade' or '$idfinalidade' = -1)
AND (property_type = '$idtipo' or '$idtipo' = -1) 
AND (region = '$iduf' or '$iduf' = -1) 
AND (city = '$idcidade' or '$idcidade' = -1)
AND (rooms = '$nquartos' or '$nquartos' = -1)
```

Comment: Como verificar se uma variável no SQL está vazia e SE sim pesquisar?

Comment: Não deu certo não

Comment: Você precisa configurar o valor padrão (no exemplo eu coloquei "-1") à todas as variáveis. Quando você especifica um valor diferente do padrão, a query irá logicamente filtrar pela variável.

Comment: Consegui, mas para finalizar com sucesso preciso que dentro do AND (rooms = '$nquartos' or '$nquartos' = -1    **ORDER BY price ASC**   ). Entendeu? preciso do ORDER BY price ASC dentro do AND, tem como?

Comment: Não é possível. Qual é sua intenção do ORDER BY dentro da cláusula WHERE?

Comment: Antes de chegar ao ORDER BY, tenho esta cilada AND ('$maiormenor' = '1' ORDER BY price ASC). Onde a variável $maiormenor precisa ter valor 1 e em seguida ordenar pelo preço. Só que esta linha dá erro, porque eu acho que tento ver se ela tem valor 1 e depois por tentar ordenar.

Comment: Você quer que a consulta retorne os resultados ordenados pelo preço quando a variável $maiormenor for igual a 1? Se sim, já é outro problema, outro assunto, outra pergunta. Poste uma nova pergunta, para facilitar aqueles quem tiverem a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37734/discussion-between-gladison-neuza-perosini-and-ricidleiv).

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia validar "Se tem valor igual à coluna ou se tem valor vazio":

```
SELECT type, property_type, city, region, neighborhood, price, rooms,
 bathrooms, parking, content, img1, urlimovel, logo, url 
FROM imoveis 
where (type = '$oquedeseja' or '$oquedeseja' = '') 
AND (goal = '$idfinalidade' or '$idfinalidade' = '')
AND (property_type = '$idtipo' or '$idtipo' = '') 
AND (region = '$iduf' or '$iduf' = '') 
AND (city = '$idcidade' or '$idcidade' = '')
AND (rooms = '$nquartos' or '$nquartos' = '');
```